# Crawling div id tags with dynamic id

Tags: python, web-crawler

I would like to crawl content from webpages with beautiful soup.

However, the div id tags have dynamic ids. Such as  In this case, the number 1 is dynamically generated. How do i use this?

I have tried this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen(
    'http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/%5Bofficial%5D-chit-chat-students-part-2-a-5526993-55.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
letters = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id":"post_message"})
print letters
```

letters returns a empty list.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @MYGz I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex inside `attrs` like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

r = urllib.urlopen(
    'http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/%5Bofficial%5D-chit-chat-students-part-2-a-5526993-55.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
letters = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id": re.compile('post_message_\d+')})
print letters
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re


r = urllib.urlopen(
    'http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/%5Bofficial%5D-chit-chat-students-part-2-a-5526993-55.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")


letters = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id": re.compile("^post_message_\d+")})
print letters
```